# How to hide a jsf element when page is loading

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am new to JSF and doing some sample login application. I need username,password only with tooltips.

I have added below extra jsf element `rich:toolTip` element added as below and my question is, how to hide this extra element.

I want to hide this element without removing from jsp.
When I inspected the source code from browser, UI is getting broken and added some extra space.

## sample.jsp

```
 <h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText value="username"/>
    <h:inputText value="username">
       <rich:toolTip value="enter uname" event="onmouseover" 
                     direction="bottom-right" layout="block"/> 
    </h:inputText>

   <h:outputText value="password"/>
     <h:inputText value="password">
     <rich:toolTip value="enter password" event="onmouseover" 
                   direction="bottom-right" layout="block"/> 
    </h:inputText>

   <rich:toolTip value="how to hide this element" event="onmouseover" 
                 direction="bottom-right" layout="block"/>
 </h:panelGrid>
```

Could anyone help on this?

Comment: ok its removed permanently, and i want to display tooltip for <rich:calendar>. on mouseover please tell me

Comment: <rich:toolTip> is not working inside <rich:calendar>, is there any way display tooltip on calendar field